# ms access русские название столбцов взамен английских

Tags: ms-access

в таблице названия столбцов на английском языке. можно ли сделать типа алиасов или не знаю как назвать на русском языке чтобы отображались вместо своих?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В своиствах колонок есть свойство "Подпись", это и есть алиас, который будет отображаться при просмотре таблицы и эти алиасы будут использоваться также в запросах и формах. Но учтите, что в тексте запросов нужно будет использовать имена колонок, а не алиасы, заданные в свойствах таблицы, так что может возникать путаница.